# How to search contacts have no group

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have a question about android contacts. I want to query all contacts have not assigned to any group, but I am not sure about the search condition, I mean, sometimes, the GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID is null If the contacts have no group, but sometimes the GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID is -1. Can anyone tell me how to search all contacts have no group?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little crude, but it works for me.  I couldn't see an easy way of finding contacts in no group without doing two queries.

It's likely that you can optimise the query to remove duplicates, thus removing the need for the 'foundIds' set.

```
    private Cursor getNoGroupsCursor() {

    Set<String> groupIds = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> foundIds = new HashSet<String>();

    // Get the group membership
    Cursor gmCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1 },
            Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'", null, null);

    while (gmCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String groupTitle = gmCursor.getString(2);
        // We need to pre-parse the group ids to find all the ones that
        // have a group
        if (groupTitle != null && !"-1".equals(groupTitle)) {
            groupIds.add(gmCursor.getString(0));
        }
    }

    gmCursor.close();

    // Get the contacts
    gmCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
            null, "2 ASC");

    // We want a projected matrix cursor that contains the contact ID and
    // group name, rather than the group ID
    MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(PROJECTION_GROUPS);

    while (gmCursor.moveToNext()) {

        String id = gmCursor.getString(0);

        if (!foundIds.contains(id) && !groupIds.contains(id)) {
            mc.addRow(new Object[] { gmCursor.getString(0),
                    gmCursor.getString(1), null, null });
            foundIds.add(id);
        }
    }

    gmCursor.close();

    return mc;
}
```

Comment: And yes, I know IDs are longs and not Strings.  Meh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now I can only use two steps search to solve this problem ,maybe we can find a better way, such as search the view_data view.